# why I am Redirected To Registration Page After White Screen when i login

Tags: android, redirect

```
package com.example.healthyme;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edUsername,edPassword;
    Button btn;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        edUsername = findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginUsername);
        edPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextLoginPassword);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.textViewNewUser);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username=edUsername.getText().toString();
                String password=edPassword.getText().toString();
                Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext(),"Healthcare",null,1);
                if(username.length()==0 || password.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Fill All Details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(db.login(username,password)==1){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // For Session Information
                        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("username",username);
                        //to save our data with key and value
                        editor.apply();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Username And Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });
    }
```

I Am Having This Issue of Redirecting.
While I Am Logging in It Is Redirecting To Wrong Page

The Code Should Redirect Me To Home Activity
Instead It Is Showing Splash Screen And
redirecting To Register Activity After Successful Login.

I Am Not Able To Understand What Is Wrong With This Since Other Intent Redirecting Is
Working Just Fine . But Login Redirection Is Not Working properly.

Comment: Can you share Splash Screen and Database class code?
Might be possible something wrong with Database code and that time app will crash and reopen app 
Inside the splash screen, there is logic in your code to redirect to the registration screen.